# Resource for infinite horizon free-endpoint optimal control problem with integral inequality constraints?

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems, optimal-control

I have been scouring multiple books on dynamic optimization, and read and studied multiple from beginning to end, including Liberzon's and Chiang's books.

All these books have sections on

1. free endpoint problems
2. infinite horizon problems
3. problems with inequality integral constraints.

However, none of them have anything on problems that have all three of these traits. It so happens to be that the combination of these three confuses me.

**I'm wondering if there is any resource that analyses such a problem in a mathematically rigorous way?**

Comment: Infinite horizon already assumes a free endpoint and for inequality constraints I would use MPC with a finite horizon and an unconstrained roll-out policy. This finite horizon should be large enough such that after the horizon the states of the system will remain within the maximal admissible set.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen, how does infinite horizon implie free endpoint? We can set $\lim_{t\to \infty} x_t=c$ as a constraint on the state variable $x_t$ for some $c$, right? About MPC, that sounds pretty complicated. I need to take the limit of the horizon to infinity, so I would have to solve the MPC problem for finite horizon and then take the solution to infinity?

Comment: Often you have asymptotic stability, so the state would converge to a constant value. For infinite horizon LQR the state will always go to zero, even though there are no terminal costs or constraints. But technically the endpoint is free.

Comment: For MPC you basically split the problem into two. The first problem is from the start to some finite horizon, which does takes inequality constraints into consideration. The second problem is from this horizon till infinity, but doesn't take inequality constraints into consideration. For example for LTI this reduces to LQR, for which the infinite horizon cost is easy to calculate.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen, I didn't say anything about a LQR. I said that it is possible to set a constraint $\lim _{t\to \infty} x_t=c$, or, in the case I'm interested in (as stated in the question), an inequality integral constraint, which boils down to $\lim_{t\to \infty} \int_0^tf(\tau, x_\tau, u_\tau)d\tau \geq 0$. The fact that for a LQR the state goes to zero  even if unconstrained does not contradict that we can set this constraint for other (non-LQR) problems.

Comment: With LQR I was just trying to give an example which both has free endpoint and infinite horizon.

Comment: Seierstad, Sydsaeter-Optimal control theory with economic applications (starting from p. 229), Grass et al. Optimal Control of Nonlinear Processes With Applications in Drugs, Corruption and Terror (Sections 3.6 - 3.9)